# Update is not working when parent child relationship is established

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table name coursemaster it has 2 column course code and course name and another table coursesubject it has 2 column course code and subject code and i applied parent child relationship.when i update a value in course code in coursemaster it displays a error

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`latest`.`coursemaster`, CONSTRAINT `coursemaster_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) REFERENCES `coursemaster` (`course_code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

But i want to update a course code in ccoursemaster table it should reflect in coursesubject coursecode.

My coursemaster table structure

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No           Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_name varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
```

Indexes: Documentation

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Field   Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit    Drop    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  course_code 13  A       
Edit    Drop    id  BTREE   Yes No  id  13  A       
Edit    Drop    course_code BTREE   Yes No  course_code 13  A
```

Coursesubject structure

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    subject_code    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
```

Indexes: Documentation

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Field   Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit    Drop    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  2   A       
Edit    Drop    subject_code    BTREE   No  No  subject_code    2   A   YES 
Edit    Drop    courseindex BTREE   No  No  course_code 2   A   YES 
subject_code    2   A   YES
```

Comment: What is your query? Are you updating `coursemaster`, or another table?

Comment: i want to update course code in coursemaster it should reflect in coursecode in coursesubject

Comment: Please show the `UPDATE` statement that got you that error. I wouldn't want to suggest something you've already tried.

Comment: i just manually edit in mysql coursemaster table #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`latest`.`coursemaster`, CONSTRAINT `coursemaster_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) REFERENCES `coursemaster` (`course_code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: If this is from a GUI you should say which one.

Comment: in mysql table i edit coursecode in coursemaster it displays 1451 error

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is seems obvious, although I can't even manage to duplicate this on a recent version of MySQL, because the server won't allow it... so exactly how you managed to get yourself in precisely this situation is unclear, but here's what I see:

```
`latest`.`coursemaster`, 
CONSTRAINT `coursemaster_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) 
REFERENCES `coursemaster` (`course_code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

You appear to have somehow managed to get the 'course_code' in 'coursemaster' actually be a  foreign key constraint against the column itself, or, if "latest" isn't the current database, then you've managed to constrain this table against a similarly-named table elsewhere on your server.

If you want the data in "table B" to change when you modify "table A", you don't declare the foreign key constraint on "table A" -- you declare it on "table B", where it *REFERENCES* table A.  `ON UPDATE CASCADE` means "cascade updates *from the other table* to *this table*."

So if you want "coursesubject" to change its "course_code" when you edit 'coursemaster' then the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint goes on "coursesubject" -- not here.

Based on what you've posted so far, the foreign key definition that is throwing the error doesn't even make sense, since a foreign key can't reference itself.